# Entity Framework 7 RC1 relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Now that I updated to ASP.NET 5 RC1, and Entity Framework 7 RC1, I expected to have relations enabled in my models. But I can't get this to work.

Here are my models:

### Post:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

### Comment:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

I have inserted manually some data in the tables and tried to access `Comments`  property of a post like this:

```
var post = context.Posts.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var comment in post.Comments)
{
    sb.Append(comment.Text);
}
```

but the `Comments` property is always null. This post has two comments in table.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use Include() extension method after Where statement: .Include(c => c.Comments)

Comment: I think EF7 doesn't do lazy loading (at least by default) so you need to `Include` your child relations.

Comment: @DavidG, you are right. Any way to configure lazy by default ?

Comment: @BeetleJuice No, it's not in EF7 yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework 7 doesn't support lazy loading (but it is on the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap#high-priority-features)) so you need to `Include` your child relations:

```
var post = context
    .Posts
    .Include(p => p.Comments)
    .Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```